# Best way to automatically cast std::string to char* without calling c_str() every time

Tags: c++, stdstring

I'm using `std::string` a lot, but various libraries that I use take a `const char*` as parameter. I'm puzzled that `std::string` does not have a conversion operator to `const char*`. So I'm looking for some way to not have to keep invoking `c_str()` all over my project.

Is there a way?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you have with invoking `c_str()`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I guess it's just all the repetitive typing and clutter in the code. Although C++ is a noisy, verbose language when you look at heavily templated code.

Comment: One way is to write wrappers to those functions and call `c_str` in there.  The you only have to do it once per function instead of once per usage.

Answer (score 4):

given the following API interface:

```
namespace someapi {
    void foo(const char* pstr);
}
```

We can do this:

```
namespace wrap_someapi
{
    inline decltype(auto) foo(const char* pstr) 
    { 
        return someapi::foo(pstr); 
    }

    inline decltype(auto) foo(std::string const& s)
    {
        return foo(s.c_str());
    }

    // or, in c++17

    inline decltype(auto) foo(std::string_view s)
    {
        return foo(s.c_str());
    }
}
```

now in the client code, rather than calling:

```
someapi::foo(s.c_str());
```

we call:

```
wrap_someapi::foo(s);
```

So we lose the verbosity while improving safety and elegance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the structure of your code?

## Use is scoped to a single block

```
{
auto str=foo.c_str();
do_x(str);
do_y(str);
do_z(str);
//etc
}
```

## All functions that accepts `const char*` are localized to a few modules

Write wrappers that accepts a `const std::string`, starting with the most common ones.